# How Many Rows om Int and Big Int

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

How many rows does datatype int and big int retrieve in their table when you work with fact table in SQL server?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand specifically what your question is or what exactly you're trying to do, but take a look at [this BOL reference on int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx).

## int

**Size**: 4 bytes
**Min**: -2,147,483,648
**Max**: 2,147,483,647

## bigint

**Size**: 8 bytes
**Min**: -9,223,372,036,854,775,808
**Max**: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

If you're asking about what are the upper limits of a sequential number (for instance, an `IDENTITY` column) then the max rows will be the **Max** values shown above, provided an initial value of 1.

Comment: For future readers, note that `IDENTITY` can also be seeded such that the negative numbers are used as well.